# Can upload content when content database is offline

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, content-database

When we set content database as `OFFLINE` in CA, can user still upload content like documents, lists etc.?

Because the description in CA says setting `OFFLINE` means no new site will be created but it doesn't say anything about new content so I am confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline content databases can still have users adding, editing, and deleting content.

If you want to prevent uploading of content, then you'll want to go to Configure Quotas and Locks in Central Admin, /_admin/sitequota.aspx, find your site, and set it to Adding Content Prevented.

Answer (score 1):

Offline Content Database means no more site collection will provision in this DB,if that is only purpose then this is not good practice rather you can limit the number of site collections in that db.but still user able to upload / edit the stuff with offline content db status.

If you marked the DB read-only at SQL server level then all site collections will be read-only.

[Side effect of Marking a Database Read-Only at CA](http://www.sharepointsteve.com/2011/02/side-effect-of-setting-content-databases-to-offline/)

> Each site collection has it’s cache of user information for it’s
>   members called the User Information List.  It primarily saves the
>   person’s account name, name and job title and it is supposed to be
>   updated to match the information in the User Profiles via a timer job.
>   When a Content Database is marked as being Offline however this timer
>   job will skip over the site collections in the Offline databases and
>   not update the User Information List.  So, eventually you will have a
>   listing of users with the incorrect job titles (due to promotions) or
>   names if they are ever changed.

If you want to prevent the user to upload the files/ data then you need to mark the site collection as read-only as Eric Mentioned.